# dotMemory - app namespaces not listed in a snapshot - only framework ones

Tags: memory-profiling, dotmemory

I'm diagnosing a custom Unit Tests (Coded UI) running library. The library  is performing tests and preparing reports at the end, pdfs. My library's namespaces are not listed in a snapshot - only Framework ones. See attached image.

[snapshot view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRVcg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you environment starts several processes, you got a memory snapshot of vstest.executionengine.x86.exe process but your library is loaded into another one.
On the "Profiling" analysis step (where the name of the process is placed) you can choose the process to analyse. Select this step, combobox with the list of processes will appear. Also there is a notification mark on the status bar (bottom-right corner) which notifies you about new process starting and helps to switch to it.

Comment: There were many processes there, strangely enough the one starting with QTAgent... was the one to be used.